# SQL Select using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I've been banging my head against my keyboard trying to get this to work.  Here's how my simple two column table (named "Test") looks:

```
part_id cust_id


1..........1

1..........1

2..........2

3..........3
```

I need to write a select statement that will list all cust_id that ordered the same part_id more than once and also lists the part_id. So far the closest I've been able to come is:

```
SELECT cust_id, COUNT(part_id)
FROM TEST
GROUP BY cust_id
HAVING COUNT(part_id) > 1;
```

Which only tells me how many customers ordered more that one part.  The same part_id is the key here.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Given your sample table, shouldn't you be using `cust_id` instead of `customer_id`? Otherwise the query looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

You're so close. Just include the `part_id` in both the SELECT and GROUP BY.

```
SELECT cust_id, part_id
FROM TEST
GROUP BY cust_id, part_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!  This was driving me crazy all afternoon.  You just saved my from a sleepless night :)